# How can I simplify a nested object which has a lot of repetitions?

Tags: javascript, object

All these three objects have the exact same property and values. Is there any way to simplify the code and make it shorter?

```
const MyMap = {
  'myObject': {
    propone: 'One',
    proptwo: 'Two',
    propthree: 'Three'
  },
  'yourObject': {
    propone: 'One',
    proptwo: 'Two',
    propthree: 'Three'
  },
  'hisObject': {
    propone: 'One',
    proptwo: 'Two',
    propthree: 'Three'
  }
};
```

Comment: what do you mean with shorter? what is the purpose of the object?

Answer (score 2):

You can store the object in its own variable and spread it into `MyMap`:

```js
const innerObject = {
  propone: 'One',
  proptwo: 'Two',
  propthree: 'Three',
};
const MyMap = {
  myObject: { ...innerObject },
  yourObject: { ...innerObject },
  hisObject: { ...innerObject }
};

console.log(MyMap);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

Or for something which allows greater flexibility in the variable names:

```js
const innerObject = {
  propone: 'One',
  proptwo: 'Two',
  propthree: 'Three',
};
const propNames = ['myObject', 'yourObject', 'hisObject'];
let MyMap = propNames.reduce((a, c) => {
  a[c] = { ...innerObject };
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(MyMap);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: auto;
}
```

With even more simplicity as suggested by [Matt Morgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3084820/matt-morgan):

`const MyMap = propNames.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c]: {...innerObject}}), {});`

Comment: I'd offer the suggestion `const MyMap = propNames.reduce((a, c) => ({...a, [c]: {...innerObject}}), {});`

Comment: Yeah, i mean, once you're going down that functional road ;)

Comment: Looks nice I agree, I left it expanded in my original answer just so it was clear what was happening but it's an elegant way to do it.